# Mapkit location opening in apple app Maps, swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I created an app that has a MapKit and displays a building. If you click on the pin it will show a description of the building and a name. How can I implement it so that when I click on the red pin I have the ability to open that destination in the apple maps app, so that I can navigate to the building through maps?

Any help would be much appreciated. I am working in Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a [tutorial](http://gottliebplanet.com/2014/11/18/working-with-mapkit-in-swift-part-1/) which can help you. Basically when a pin callout is clicked a new view is displayed. Here you can put your mapview. Also before the new view is presented, pass the data to it's controller (data for new map).

Comment: Could you update the tutorial link. The current one is dead. Thanks